# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty "

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть код, телеграм бот. при нажатии на кнопку выдает фразы из списка.
Когда список доходит до конца - выдает ошибку:

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty"

это из-за того что список дошел до конца и там пусто?

как мне сделать что бы список начинался заново?

мой код:

```
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types
from collections import deque

def get_first_element_in_the_queue(array: list) -> str:
    first_element = array[0]
    array.rotate(-1)
    return first_element

f = open('/Users/marina/ukrwrite/ch.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
ch = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

f = open('/Users/marina/ukrwrite/useful.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
useful = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

f = open('/Users/marina/ukrwrite/ra.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
ra = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

ch_q = deque(ch)
useful_q = deque(useful)
ra_q = deque(ra)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
        markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1=types.KeyboardButton("челендж")
        item2=types.KeyboardButton("корисне")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("рекомендовані авторки")
        markup.add(item1)
        markup.add(item2)
        markup.add(item3)
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Привіт. ',  reply_markup=markup)
        handle_text(message=None, useful_q=useful_q)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text.strip() == 'челендж':
        ch_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(ch_q)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ch_q)
    if message.text.strip() == 'корисне':
        useful_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(useful_q)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, useful_q)
    if message.text.strip() == 'рекомендовані авторки':
        ra_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(ra_q)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ra_q)
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так

```
def get_first_element_in_the_queue(queue: deque):
    first_element = queue.popleft()
    queue.append(first_element)
    return first_element
```